# NodeJS: Write to JSON file removes existing data

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, writetofile

I am working on this method:

```
router.use(bodyparser.json());
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    let rooms;
    //let roomID = methoden.idErstellen(rooms, filename);

    try {
        rooms = {
            //id: roomID,
            id:req.body.id,
            name: req.body.name
        };
        //createRessource(filename)
        let data = JSON.stringify(rooms, null, 2);
        fs.writeFile(filename, data, (err)=> {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Data written to file')
        });
        //res.status(201).send(rooms);
    } catch (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
    refresh();
});
```

The method adds a new data set to the JSON file, but removes all the existing ones. I can't figure out what the problem with this is

Comment: writeFile will continuously write to same file and over-write it if the name is the same.

Comment: If you plan to store this way, consider not putting all the files in a single directory, but instead making many directories as you grow /as9 /asui /asd9 /sad /s05 /s0fd and so forth and maybe name each item an UUID so it doesn't clash.

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem. the method should add new data. i think the problem might be with JSON.stringify

Comment: You only need to use it like this, JSON.stringify(rooms); and store that string to any file you want.

Comment: `rooms` is only going to contain the data from your request.  `stringify` is doing exactly what it's supposed to.  You could read the file in, then add the new room to the (parsed) file, then write the file back out.  But there isn't anything that will magically append to JSON in a file with a new fragment like you're trying to do.

Comment: The only way to add to an existing JSON text file is to read the entire existing file into memory, parse the JSON text into a Javascript object, add something to the data object, stringify it back to JSON text and write that JSON as the entire new file.  JSON is not a format that can be easily added to incrementally on disk.  Formats that can be easily added to incrementally are CSV or most databases.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to implement a database for these cases. Within the rapid prototype I will choose write into a new file. Thanks all

Answer (score -1):

Try using `fs.appendFile`

```
fs.appendFile(filename, data, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Data written to file successfully');
});
```

Comment: this causes the problem that the data set is added to the JSON file, but not correctly within the curly brackets